# Convert date type January 09, 2012 to MM/DD/YYYY c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

I am using following code:

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact(
    dateString,
    "MMddyyyy",
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

But getting error as String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Can anyone let me know how to get the exact format?

Comment: `January 09, 2012` is not of the format `MMddyyyy`.  Read up on `ParseExact`, or just use `Parse`

Comment: You're on the right track, you just are using the wrong format string as @Jonesy points out.  How about you try different format strings with `DateTime.ToString` until you find one that matches your input, exactly.

Comment: Yeah, you might want to just read the [MSDN Documentation on ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx). They even give [examples!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx#code-snippet-2)

Comment: [Here's what your current format string actually matches](http://ideone.com/obGBz6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just have the wrong format. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that to parse a string like that you'd need a format like `MMMM dd, yyyy`.

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,
    "MMMM dd, yyyy",
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Take note in the documentation to the following:

- `MMMM` - The full name of the month.
- `dd`   - The day of the month, from 01 through 31.
- `yyyy` - The year as a four-digit number.

Comment: @user3477335 You should accept the answer that best resolves your question by clicking the check mark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
string date = "January, 09 2012";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMMM, dd yyyy", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code:

```
string dateInput = "January 09, 2012";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateInput, "MMMM dd, yyyy", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);

string dateOutput = dt.ToString("MMddyyyy");
```

**Output:**

01092012

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try Following Code**

string DateFormate = "01/22/2013 10:00:00";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateFormate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateFormate = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");